# Transformations that preserve beta random variables

Tags: probability, bayesian

Consider a random variable $x$ distributed according to a beta distribution $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$.

Now draw a sample $x\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, and transform this sample via some function $f$, i.e., $y=f(x)$. Note that $f$ could be stochastic in that it represents a conditional distribution $p(y\mid x)$.

What conditions on $f$ ensure that $y$ is also distributed according to some beta distribution, $\text{Beta}(\alpha',\beta')$?

Comment: I am guessing this means: What conditions on $f$ assure that $f(x)$ will have a Beta distribution regardless of which Beta distribution $x$ has? $\qquad$

Comment: Yes (with the emphasis that $f$ could be a conditional distribution: $y\sim p(\cdot\mid x)$ since there seem to be very few non-trivial deterministic functions that ensure $y$ is beta)

Comment: One obvious example is $x\mapsto1-x. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeah, unfortunately there doesn’t seem to be much we can say in the deterministic case.

Comment: Are you looking for sufficient conditions? Necessary conditions? Conditions that are necessary and sufficient? Any a priori contraints on $f$ (e.g. monotonic) or not? If $f$ can a priori be anything, there's quite a lot of freedom in choosing it.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I mentioned in the bounty comment (which oddly only appears on the web version for me) that I am looking for “as complete of a characterization as possible” so ideally necessary and sufficient conditions. If I had to choose, sufficient conditions would be more useful for me. Nothing is assumed about $f$.

Comment: And which of the parameters $\alpha,\beta,\alpha',\beta'$ are given? Is the question "For given parameters, when is $f$ such a transformation" or "When is $f$ such a transformation for *some* parameter values"?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given. I am interested in characterizing the functions $f$ such that $y$ follows _some_ beta distribution.

Comment: An obvious sufficient condition in the deterministic case is $f = G^{-1} \circ F$, where $F$ and $G$ are the respective CDFs, but I somehow I doubt this is the kind of answer that the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Deterministic case

Notation: $F$ is the cdf of $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ and $G$ is the cdf of $\text{Beta}(\alpha',\beta')$. Note that $\alpha,\beta$ are known and fixed. Observe that $F$ and $G$ are strictly increasing bijections $(0,1) \to (0,1)$.

Let $u := F(x)$ and $v := G(y)$. Suppose we have $y=f(x)$ with a deterministic function $f$. Now define
$$
h : (0,1) \to (0,1) : h(u) := G(f(F^{-1}(u))) = v.
$$

We know that $u \sim U(0,1)$. On the other hand, $y \sim G$ is equivalent to $v \sim U(0,1)$, which is equivalent to saying that $h$ maps a $U(0,1)$ random variable to a (possibly different) $U(0,1)$ random variable.

So a **sufficient and necessary condition** for $y \sim G$ is that $f = G^{-1} \circ h \circ F$ with any mapping $h: (0,1) \to (0,1)$ that preserves the measures of all Borel sets.

Now there are quite many such mappings. Some easy examples are $h(u)=u$ and $h(u)=1-u$, but more generally you could, for example, divide $(0,1)$ to $r$ intervals of length $1/r$, and $h$ could shuffle and mirror these intervals arbitrarily, like
$$
h(u) = \begin{cases}
 u+1/3 & \text{if $0<u \le 1/3$}\\
 u-1/3 & \text{if $1/3 < u \le 2/3$}\\
 u & \text{if $2/3 < u < 1$.}
 \end{cases}
$$
(Also, $h$ could map some zero-measure set wherever you want, like $h(u)=u^7/\pi$ whenever $u \in \mathbb Q$.) This is a pretty wild collection of functions and I'm not sure this is what the OP wants.

### Deterministic and monotonous

Things get much more orderly if we impose an extra requirement that *$f$ is monotonous* (or that it is *continuous*). Then also $h$ must be monotonous and the only possibilities are $h(u)=u$ and $h(u)=1-u$.

If we want $f$ to be increasing, the only possibility is $h(u)=u$ and thus $f = G^{-1} \circ F$, where $G$ is the cdf of some Beta distribution. I guess this is the neatest condition you can get, if you want sufficient and necessary, because the inverse cdf's of Beta distributions do not in general have closed form expressions.

For just **sufficient conditions**, hmm ... if $x \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha,1)$ then $F(x) = x^\alpha$. Then $f(x)=x^r$ with $r>0$ is a sufficient condition, because then $y \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha/r,1)$. But this is a very restricted family of beta distributions so probably not what is wanted.

For just **necessary conditions** ... Empirically, by plotting $f=G^{-1} \circ F$ for various Beta cdf functions $F,G$, it seems that $f$ has at most one inflection point in the interval $(0,1)$. Perhaps this would not be too hard to prove. But this is a relatively weak condition and nothing like sufficient.

[image: Some monotonous mappings from Beta to Beta]

### Stochastic case

We have $x$, which has some beta distribution with cdf $F$, and we are looking for a conditional distribution $p(y|x)$ such that $y$ has a beta distribution with cdf $G$. If we again transform $u=F(x)$ and $v=G(y)$, we are looking for a conditional distribution $p(v|u)$, or equivalently a joint distribution $p(u,v)=p(v|u)p(u)$ where $u,v$ are uniform on $(0,1)$. Now such distributions are plenty: **$p(u,v)$ can be any bivariate [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory))**. So here, without further restrictions, the possibilities are even wilder than in the deterministic case.